# set navigation bar back to default

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uiimagepickercontroller

In my app's `UIApplicationDelegate` I am customizing the background of the navigation bar with this code:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:myImage] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Everything is working fine, but when launching for example the image picker, I would like to set the navigation bar back to default, and then when the user has picked the picture, restore the custom background. Is that possible?

I have tried setting the `backgroundColor` property to `nil` but it does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing the appearance for UINavigationBar (which will affect every navigation bar), make a subclass of UINavigationBar, then use that in your appearance code.

Then in your navigation controller, set your navigation bar class to that of the one you subclassed.